# Не удается добавить свои кнопки соц сетей addthis в тему wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Есть в теме *wordpress* подключенный скрипт соц сетей [addthis](http://www.addthis.com)
(изменил стандартный *id* на `pubid=ra-559fd5ab72c4dfba`, но это ничего мне не дало).

Вот так реализован его вывод.

```js
$.getScript('http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-559fd5ab72c4dfba#async=1', function() {
  if (window.addthis) {
    window.addthis.init();
    window.addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox");
    window.addthis.counter('.addthis_counter');
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="d_inline_middle"><?php _e('Share this:', MAD_BASE_TEXTDOMAIN) ?></span>
  <div class="d_inline_middle m_left_5 addthis_widget_container">
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
      <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
      <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    <?php MAD_BASE_FUNCTIONS::enqueue_script( 'addthis'); ?>
  </div>
</div>

public function register_scripts() { wp_register_script(MAD_PREFIX . 'addthis', 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-559fd5ab72c4dfba#async=1', array('jquery')); }
```

Хочу виртуальный заменить на свой реальный. Для подключения на сайт по инструкции нужно сделать:

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript"   src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-559fd5ab72c4dfba" async="async"></script>
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
```

Но, т.к. это *wordpress*, делаю это так:

```
function add_this_script(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'addscript', 'https://www.s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-559fd5ab72c4dfba#async=1');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_this_script' );
```

и пытаюсь выводить в:

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
```

но ничего не получается, что только уже только не делал: оставлял только подключенный скрипт, заменял в скрипте класс на `addthis_sharing_toolbox`, но ничего не получается..

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в самом сервисе, он сам устанавливает какие кнопки показывать - [здесь](http://www.jeffalytics.com/customize-addthis-wordpress-plugin/) можно почитать. решение такое - принудительное выставление своих кнопок, т.е.

```html
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
  <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_linkedin"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_reddit"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_stumbleupon"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_instapaper"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_pocket"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_diigo"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
  <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
  <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>

<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Осталось только проблема с pinterest - выводится мелкая кнопка, вместо большой как должно быть